# Automata programming language

Tags: programming-languages, theory, turing-machines, automata-theory

Do you know any programming language that implements abstract machines like Turing machines and Finite State Automatons?

That is, process the following input:

- A 5-tuple ([The notorious ⟨Q,Σ,δ,q0,F⟩ from formal languages 101](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory)), a [7-tuple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine#Formal_definition) for Turing machines or any other formal representation of an abstract machine.
- An input word.

And tell me if the input word was an accepting word.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [J programming language](http://jsoftware.com/) provides a finite state machine processor as a primitive symbol of the language. The documentation for that symbol is [here](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d332.htm).

That said, let me warn that Sequential Machine is not a suitable starting point for the J language. It's an advanced component. Attempting to use it without significant familiarity with J will likely result in much frustration.

An accessible essay that demonstrates the use of J's Sequential Machine is [Huffman Coding](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Huffman%20Coding).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the Turing machine. I'm sure people have written simulators out there. For the FSAs, you could just use a regular expression. :)

Comment: I'm looking for a broader language that would utilize the tuple notation.